# C++: Change value of class by method of another class - bug?

Tags: c++

I've got weird thing which, by my experience, I can call bug in C++. When I call this program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo {
public:
    int a;
    foo(int a = 0) : a(a) {}
} a1;

class bar {
    foo a;
public:
    bar(foo a = a1) : a(a) {
        a.a = 1;
        cout << a.a << endl;
    }
    void print_a() {
        cout << a.a << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    bar zz;
    zz.print_a();
    a1.a = 2;
    bar zz1;
    zz1.print_a();
}
```

The output is:

```
1
0
1
2
```

I do expect to be able to change values of internal members of my class, like the **a** value of the object of **foo** class inside **bar** class. When I change the **a.a** value in **bar** constructor, it looks like I changed only local variable. What is the mechanism of this process? C++ does not treat variables inside its class as constant parameters, because I can as well get counter which is changed by methods. But when counter is one class more deeper, the structure seems to collapse.

Comment: I think it might be easier to understand if the function parameter and the class data member had different names.

Comment: Nothing wrong here, `int a` is public in `class foo` (means anyone free to change it in non-const context), and constructor `bar` is non-constant. But if you declare `int print_a()` in `class bar` with `const` specifier, you forbid changing of `a.a` inside `print_a()` method.

Comment: Geez, in order to parse `bar(foo a = a1) : a(a) ` I'd have to resort to the standard. Which a is which in `a(a)`??

Comment: And in ` a.a = 1;` the first a is probably the parameter which was passed by value, so the line won't change a thing outside the ctor. Ah, that's what Mike said, too.

Comment: @PeterSchneider, I think it's pretty sensible that the `a` following the colon looks for members and the other one uses normal function scope lookup. I don't particularly like them having the same name, though.

Comment: @chris True. And the parameter eclipses the member of the same name, here with the initialization parameter where it is right and later in the body, where it is wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Within the constructor body, argument names hide member names, so as you surmised, you're modifying the function argument `a`, not the member `a`.

You can refer to the member as `this->a` or `bar::a` to disambiguate, if you don't want to rename either variable.